# countif adding up how many are in a certain month

Tags: excel, count, countif

I am trying to get a formula that counts up how many cells contain this month and how many cell contain < than current month eg: in a column

```
March 2015
January 2016
April 2016
May 2016
May 2016
May 2016 
June 2016
```

And then have a cell at the bottom that tells me 3 for May and 3 out of date

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15838543/excel-count-number-of-occurences-by-month

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28722033/excel-countifs-count-months-in-date-range

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21879036/excel-countif-using-month-and-letter-as-criterias

3 possible duplicates?

Comment: Technically you only have two months less than May, excluding June.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data were in column A and you had 15 points, then the following two formulae should work.

Number of cells in the current month:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A15, "5/1/2016")
```

Number of cells before the current month:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A15,"<5/1/2016")
```

Comment: Thank you the second one has worked but the first one hasn't and will it update at the months go by

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  How does the first formula not work?